# $|f(x,y)| \le K |x-y|$: is there a name for this property?

Tags: analysis, continuity

Here $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $K>0$ is a constant. It's a bit like being contractive or Lipschitz, but not the same as either of those.

Comment: It implies uniform continuity but is apparently a bit stronger than that.  It is implied by having a bounded derivative, but again it is a bit weaker than that.  If we knew more about $f$, perhaps one gap or the other could be closed.

Comment: I don't really think there is a specific name for this kind of function

Answer (score 2):

One may compare this to the notion of a function with a [modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) that is *constant*.

As @lisyarus points out, for a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ to have a constant modulus of continuity $K \gt 0$ would mean:

$$ |f(x,y) - f(u,v)| \le K ||(x,y) - (u,v) || $$

whereas here we are told there exists some constant $K \gt 0$:

$$ |f(x,y)| \le K|x-y| $$

In particular this latter implies that the function $f(x,x)$ "restricted to the diagonal" is identically zero.  We cannot infer this property simply from uniform continuity or other smoothness assumptions on $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify? Constant modulus of continuity means $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K|x-y|$, while the question states $|f(x,y)| \leq K|x-y|$, which is different.

Comment: @lisyarus:  You make a very good point (I exercise the usual excuse of posting without benefit of coffee as I hurried down to the local cafe).  I'll revise my "answer" to reflect your note.